# Strange "file not found" error in ruby sinatra web app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin, slim-lang

I'm creating a sinatra web app with a mongodb database. I use mongomapper to do the mappings. The web server is thin and I'm using slim as a templating language.

file ./config/config.ru:

```
$_DB_SERVER = "localhost"
$_APP_PATH = "~/Documents/Aptana_Workspace/Parameters_crud"

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)

require "#{$_APP_PATH}/main.rb"
require "#{$_APP_PATH}/models/parameter.rb"

map '/' do
  run CORE::Main
end
```

file main.rb:

```
module CORE

  class Main < Sinatra::Base
    use Rack::Flash

    configure :development do

      enable :sessions, :logging, :dump_errors, :inline_templates
      enable :methodoverride
      set :root, $_APP_PATH
      logger = Logger.new($stdout)

    end

    get '/' do
      slim :index
    end
  end
end
```

**END**

error encountered:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - ~/Documents/Aptana_Workspace/Parameters_crud/views/index.slim
```

I'm 100% sure this file does exist. What could be the cause of this error? If you need more information, please leave a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `File.expand_path` like this -

```
$_APP_PATH = File.expand_path("~/Documents/Aptana_Workspace/Parameters_crud", __FILE__)
```